# Is it possible to store visitors IPs in wp_postmeta table?

Tags: database, post-meta, user-meta, ip

Or in any of the other 11 Wordpress tables. I also need to store: submission date, name,  contact number in the same table.

What approach would be best? A custom table or using a standard table?

Comment: What are they submitting?  If they're creating posts then yes the post meta table would be ideal to store those four pieces of data.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Thank-you for taking an interest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's information that logically belongs to a **post/page** - you store it in `postmeta` (with [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function). If it's something that pertains to a **user** - `usermeta` table is for you. More still, there's [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) in case you have a plugin that needs to persist any settings.

From your question it is somewhat unclear which of these would be best for you. What's a "*submission date*"? The name and contact number, I'm guessing, are for a user, and so would belong in the `usermeta`. Function [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) is a good place to start.